# What are the best option to migrate the EMC Isilon on AWS cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, migration, data-migration, emc

we have requirement of migrating EMC Isilon SAN storage which is of size 1.5 Peta bytes. What is the best service we should choose in AWS cloud? We are exploring the S3 IA currently. Other than AWS what might be other good option on cloud? How much code changes we have to do after changing the storage from Isilon to AWS S3? Currently about 20% content of Isilon is frequently accessed.

Answer (score 0):

ExploringApple,

One of the best options to move Isilon storage to the cloud is now part of the most recent Isilon software release.  On 2/2/2016. EMC Isilon released (GA'ed) it's 8th generation OneFS software which includes CloudPools.  For the 80% of data that is infrequently accessed, CloudPools may be the best solution for this data.  There are a number of advantages with this new feature set.

1. The move to the cloud is seamless. The metadata is local, while data portion of the content is moved to the cloud.  To users and apps the data appears local.  E.G.  You can ls the file and it appears local to the filesystem.
2. No gateway is required, and you can continue to use a single filesystem and namespace in your existing environment and natively tier inactive data to the cloud.
3. The data is secure.  When the data portion of the file is placed in the cloud, it is sharded into a 1MB chunk size, compressed and encrypted.  The data that lands in the cloud target is now opaque and only accessible via Isilon.  You can still login to your cloud provider and report on billing, metered data and capacity.
4. There are a number of choices in terms of cloud providers.  AWS is supported as is EMC's Virtustream and Azure for public cloud choices. In terms of private cloud, Isilon and EMC's ECS products are supported depending upon your needs for, scale out file or scale out, geo-distributed object store respectively.

Contact your Islion/EMC rep to learn more about CloudPools.  Let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: Thanks lot for reply, But what will be the cost benefit it will give? Also is it possible to migrate my existing isilon data on cloudPools? What are the best points to convince to client to use CloudPools and not replace it completely.

Comment: TCO and cost benefit are typically unique to each environment.  One example of the cost benefit would be to extend the use of Isilon in the datacenter.

Comment: On to your second question. Yes, Isilon is designed to seamlessly work with existing data. For users and applications, it is seamless. The administrator creates a CloudPools and determines how to tier data to the cloud provider. In terms of the best points to communicate with a client, I would recommend 1-4 listed above. You can also learn more about the product on EMC's product pages, just search for Isilon or Data Lake